# copyFile works in IDE but not in production

Tags: java, netbeans

I need to copy a file from a working directory to an archiving directory, so I use the following code:

```
private void copyToArchive(Date today) {
    try {
        File source = new File("final.txt");
        String msg = "getting source file " + source;
        displayMessage(msg, good); // good points to a sound file
        File destination = new File("archives\\final." + today + ".txt");
        msg = "getting destination file " + destination;
        displayMessage(msg, good);
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);
        msg = "finished trying to copy file";
        displayMessage(msg, good);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        String message = "archiving failed";
        displayMessage(message, bad);
        Logger.getLogger(FileManagerController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The thing is, this works fine in the IDE, but in production it only succeeds as far as the declaration of "destination." In the IDE I get the "finished trying to copy file" notification (as well as the copied file in the subdirectory "archives"), but in production I get NEITHER the confirmation NOR the "archiving failed" notification from the IOException catch (and no copied file in the subdirectory).

Help?

(I run NetBeans 7.4 and the program runs on JDK version 1.7.0_55 (can't upgrade because another java program we run will not run on later java versions)).

Comment: Is this a desktop or web application?

Comment: Desktop ... sorry. Running on Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried to give it a full path, such as `File destination = new File("c:\\temp\test.txt")`?  Maybe windows or some security policy is preventingi you from writing to a certain directory?

Comment: I have not, because this is used on different machines, so it would be better to use the directory as relative.

Comment: Did you check the log file for the error message? Your `displayMessage` might be having an issue and not displaying the message. Another reason might be that `copyFile` might be throwing a non-IO exception (it can throw NPE for example) which is caught by a method higher in the hierarchy and getting ignored.

Comment: I see no errors thrown...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is your problem or not, but

```
File destination = new File("archives\\final." + today + ".txt");
```

should probably be

```
File destination = new File("archives","final." + today + ".txt");
```

for portability to file systems where `\\` is not the directory separator.

Comment: I did not know about this for portability. I have made the change, but it does not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Java Working Directory. It can be retrieved with:

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

This will return your project's path.

So, on your case, your code would look like:

```
private void copyToArchive(Date today) {
    try {
        File source = new File("final.txt");
        String msg = "getting source file " + source;
        displayMessage(msg, good); // good points to a sound file
        File destination = new File(workingDir + "archives\\final." + today + ".txt");
        msg = "getting destination file " + destination;
        displayMessage(msg, good);
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);
        msg = "finished trying to copy file";
        displayMessage(msg, good);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        String message = "archiving failed";
        displayMessage(message, bad);
        Logger.getLogger(FileManagerController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

IMPORTANT: maybe you would need as well writing file permissions. Here you have a very good example of how to read/set rights: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-the-file-permission-in-java/

Comment: Thank you, but the working directory is ... working. The original file ("final.txt") is produced just fine in the method that calls copyToArchive(Date today). I have made a work-around wherein the calling method produces TWO files, one called final.txt and the second, which would be the copied file, but it was twice as much programming. I would love it if I could figure out why the copyFile is not working ...